# Jest --coverage tests error: 'Nothing was returned from render.'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, test-coverage

All of my components pass their tests when I run yarn test or yarn test [filename]. However, when I run tests with the --coverage flag I am getting the following error, pointing to the Wrapper of the custom render function I created. The custom render function is more or less copy/pasted from the react-testing-library documentation: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup

None of the following commands I have tried so far worked: yarn test --coverage, yarn test --coverage --watchAll=false, yarn test --collectCoverage, npm run test --coverage, npm run test --coverage --watchAll=false

**Error:**

`Error: Uncaught [Error: Wrapper(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]`

```
  82 |              );
  83 |      };
> 84 |      return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
     |             ^
  85 | };
  86 | 
  87 | const render = (ui: ReactElement, { store = createStore(appReducer, initialState as AppApiStore), ...renderOptions } = {}): RenderResult => {`
```

**Custom render function:**

```
    const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }): ReactElement => {
        return (
            <MemoryRouter>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <IntlProvider messages={messagesEn} locale="en">
                        {children}
                    </IntlProvider>
                </Provider>
            </MemoryRouter>
        );
    };
    return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions });
```

**Test:**

```
test('App', () => {
    render(<App />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Startpage/));
    expect(screen.getByText('Start page')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/pubsub-js": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.36",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "less": "^3.11.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "^5.4.1",
    "react-media": "^1.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.18.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.11.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:ts": "eslint --ext=jsx,ts,tsx src",
    "eslint-check": ".eslintrc",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "pretty-quick": "pretty-quick",
    "build:check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "pretty-quick --staged",
      "eslint --fix --config .eslintrc --fix",
      "git add --patch"
    ]
  }
}
```